# How to calculate and store scores in django betting game?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, triggers

I'm working on my first django project which is a sport betting game.

My models are:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    home_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    away_goals = models.IntegerField(default=None)


class Bet(models.Model):
    gameid = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_goals = models.IntegerField()
    away_goals = models.IntegerField()
    score = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
```

logic for calculating scores is:

```
WHEN polls_bet.home_goals = polls_game.home_goals AND polls_bet.away_goals = polls_game.away_goals THEN 2 
WHEN polls_game.home_goals > polls_game.away_goals AND polls_game.home_goals > polls_game.away_goals THEN 1 
WHEN polls_bet.home_goals < polls_bet.away_goals AND polls_game.home_goals < polls_game.away_goals THEN 1 
ELSE 0
```

I was able to solve it easily using database view that combines all data in one table but it seems that it does not play well with django migrations..

So I was thinking about sql trigger after update of game goals, but then I don't know how to pass conditions like user's id.

2nd idea is to create additional 'scores' table with:

```
gameid, 
userid, 
betid,
score
```

But then again I don't know how to calculate scores.
Please advice how this should be done properly, without using sql view. I appreciate all answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a 'score' property on the Bet model to solve this easily. Please refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods).

Your property implementation will be something like:

```
@property
def score(self):
    if (self.home_goals == self.game__home_goals and
            self.away_goals == self.game__away_goals):
        return 2
    if (self.game__home_goals > self.game__away_goals):
        return 1
    if (self.home_goals < self.away_goals and
            self.game__home_goals < self.home_goals):
        return 1
    return 0
```

On a side note, the normal naming convension for a foreignkey relation is the model name in lowercase. So it becomes 'game' and 'user' instead of 'gameid' and 'userid'. Also I believe you have some typos on the second condition.

Comment: Thank you Jose, this sounds really great! 

Unfortunately when I removed score from my bet model and added it as property (pasted your code) and then migrated - score field disapeared from my bet table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Patr01, a property is a calculated value and it is not stored in the database. If you want to store it  in the database, you need to update it manually, but you can use the same logic.

Comment: I need  to store it so then I can sum it for each user, right? What do you mean I have to update it manually? Thank you for your consideration, those are my first steps :)

Comment: @Patr01, you need to know when to update the score as  the result may not be known when the bet is placed. Probably a post_save signal on the Game model and update the Bet model when the game is complete.  see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/